# Encryption on a rooted Canadian S5 (SM 900W8)

Tags: root-access, encryption, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am trying to encrypt my Canadian S5 and have high and low online for the multiple answers given to me on Google and XDA. I can't seem to do it either way.

What happens is when I run the encryption I get the screen saying encryption and then everything goes blank and nothing happens when it reboots (after a few seconds). How ever it will encrypt an SD card installed.

As I mentioned before I have looked everywhere and can't seem to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Padraig.